# How to post on Google Buzz?

Tags: c#, google-buzz

How can I post my message to Google Buzz? Is there an API?

Answer (score 8):

It's in the usual place:)

http://code.google.com/apis/buzz/

As of the time of this answer:

> Over the next several months Google Buzz will introduce an API for developers, including full/read write support for posts with the Atom Publishing Protocol, rich activity notification with Activity Streams, delegated authorization with OAuth, federated comments and activities with Salmon, distributed profile and contact information with WebFinger, and much, much more.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to post short messages you can use a much more simple way. Send an email to `buzz@gmail.com`.

Example using gmail account:

```
public static void Buzz(string message)
{
    string from, to, pass;

    from = "youracc@gmail.com";
    to = "buzz@gmail.com";
    pass = "yourpass";

    var smtp = new SmtpClient
    {
        Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
        Port = 587,
        EnableSsl = true,
        DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
        UseDefaultCredentials = false,
        Credentials = new NetworkCredential(from, pass)
    };

    smtp.Send(from, to, message, String.Empty);
}
```

Then just call

```
Buzz("Hello world");
```

Answer (score 0):

Buzz API are available now.
http://googlecode.blogspot.com/2010/05/introducing-google-buzz-api.html

Answer (score 0):

There is an API: http://code.google.com/apis/buzz/docs/
There are also client libraries: http://code.google.com/apis/buzz/docs/libraries.html for  Java, PHP and Python.

There are also "hyperlink" and Javascript APIs available: http://code.google.com/apis/buzz/buttons_and_gadgets.html

Answer (score -1):

There is no API yet to read and write directly to and from a buzz stream, but [it is in development and "coming soon"](http://code.google.com/apis/buzz/documentation/#coming-soon)

There are of course APIs to pull things into a buzz stream (how connected sites work), so you could always write to something that does have a direct API and then connect that into your buzz stream.